# Is this behavior showing that I have a memory problem?

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, gurobi

I have a LP problem with ~4 million variables and ~4 million constraints. I use gurobi to solve it. My PC has 4 cores and 8 GB memory.

According to the log file, it takes ~100 seconds to find the optimal solution. Then the CPU is released, but still almost full memory is being used. It hangs there, doing nothing for hours until it continues to run the script (e.g. print command) after the solving.

results = opt.solve(model, tee=True)

print("model solved")

I used barrier method with crossover disabled, this worked best. I also tried different number of threads to be used, it turned out using 4 is the best in terms of the hanging time (but still hours).

This hanging significantly increases the total run time, which is not desired.

I plan to upgrade the memory, but want to get answers from the community that it indeed is a memory issue. Is this a memory problem?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the problem does not fit in memory and virtual memory (i.e. disk) is used. This is called thrashing when it is really bad. It can bring your machine to its knees. Depending on the number of nonzeros in the problem, the presolve statistics and the number of threads you are using, you need at least 16 GB (and may be more like 32 GB).

Also: try to reduce the number of threads Gurobi is using. It may be better to use 1 thread (after benchmarking which LP algorithm works best: primal or dual simplex or a barrier method). By default a concurrent LP method is used: use different LP solvers in parallel, significantly increasing the memory footprint.

Comment: Also, I had experiences where loading only few variables at the end of solving nearly just avoid this kind of hang for very large problems. This suggests that retrieving variable values from the solver to Pyomo is very slow, especially when RAM is too small.

Comment: I must add, since I do not say that RAM size is always the cause of this: small RAM makes your computer prone to swapping. It is already sort of slow to retrieve all non zero variables, but when it starts swapping, it becomes a completely other kind of game. OP might still get those hangs after upgrading RAM, but if it allows his computer to stop swapping, they should be way shorter.